# How can I update UI of an app that is in the background without bringing it to the foreground?

Tags: android, user-interface, alarmmanager, onresume, background-foreground

I have an Android app with an AlarmManager that repeats every 15 minutes. Depending on the results from this I want to update the UI, but I don't want Android to bring the app to the foreground if it doesn't have focus already.

How can I do this? Alternatively, how can I make the UI updates run in onResume?

I'm calling methods like `public static void updateRunningStatusTextView(Boolean inStatus)` on the main activity from services and classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your first option can't happen. There is `postInvalidate()` that can update the `View` from a non `UI` thread but this is available

> ...only when this View is attached to a window.

according to the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29)

> Alternatively, how can I make the UI updates run in onResume?

This depends on many things such as the `View`, the data, and what you have in your code but you could set the data in a static class or save it in something like `SharedPreferences` then retrieve the data from there, say a `String` to use in `setText()` of a `TextView`

Comment: I am already saving the relevant variables in sharedpreferences, so I guess putting an updateUI() method in onResume is the way to go. If the app has focus I want to update immediately though, how would I implement that?

Comment: I guess it kind of depends on what you have going on but one option is to call `invalidate()` on the `Views` that need to be refreshed

Comment: I mean the "check if app is in foreground"-process..?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not) it should give you what you need

Comment: I went for the Boolean isVisible-method, seems to work fine so far. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // update UI here from cached values
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Isn't onResume a better place to handle this, since it gets called after onRestart anyway and catches a couple other cases too? And do I really need to use a Handler and Runnable?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't. If it is in background, you don't need to update the UI!

Then you just need to update the UI when you resume your app (onResume), with the latest data you have.