# How to detect when an activity is in the foreground and launch another activity instead

Tags: android

A client of mine has some proprietary android devices that he needs to lock the settings for. Basically he wants a service that will detect when the settings activity is in the foreground and switch to a "type your password" activity which will then allow the settings app to be run if the password is correct.

My question is simply how can I detect when another application is in the foreground?
As a follow-up, is there a simple way to bring my application to the front when this is detected?

Comment: This is maybe something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [`ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) class for Android 4.0 and higher. You register this listener in your Application class and it will be notified about every activity started. You can implement a counter for all started activities and if at least one activity is started, the app is foreground.

For older devices every activity needs to call a callback method of Application to report that it was started.

Comment: Fantastic. That's exactly what I needed. These devices run 4.0 so that should work just fine for me.

Comment: I will accept your answer in eight minutes when I am allowed to.