# How to check if Android application goes to foreground?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to check if the Android application goes to foreground? Maybe anything callback function? Any idea or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried onResume()

Comment: hi please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not

Answer (score 1):

You can write code for callback activity in `onRestart()` Method.

Comment: `onRestart()` will fire if the application re-starts, but when Application comes from back to foreground, normally `onResume()` gets fire.

Comment: whenever you press back button and come on foreground activity that time onRestart() will be called you can try

Comment: Agree, but this happens only if the activity has destroyed , not else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not check this answer

Comment: i checked again. onRestart() method called when you press back no matter onDestroyed() called or not.

Comment: in your question you didn't mention using home button press. you mention callback option.

Comment: i checked again when you press home button and again launch your app that time onRestart() and onResume() both method will be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).yourActivity.getPackageName()
```

This method can get the foreground app package name.

you can use thread listen change.

Answer (score 0):

As per android life cycle `onResume` and `onStart` will be called once your activity comes to foreground. For more details [Android life cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)