# Launch Application or show Dialog from Notification Area

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In my application, I have implemented GCM and I want to show an **AlertDialog** or Open **Application's Activity** depending upon the **state** of my Application, i.e. if my application is at Foreground state then upon clicking on Notification I want to display an **AlertDialog** and if the Application is in Background state then the Notification should launch my **Application**.

Please let me know is there any way through which I can check the Applications status on clicking **Notification**.

**I want to know that from Notification Area on from the Application**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Closed this question as it's duplicate of [check android application is in foreground or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not).

Comment: @Paresh I want to check that from Push Notification's Click not from inside of my Application

Comment: Just try to implement and update with your R&D, as of now it's look almost similar issue.

Comment: And given questions links in comments are almost similar to your issue. Look into it and try to implement by your own!

Comment: I have asked here because I have done R&D for it. Else I'll not post a similar question again.

Comment: Check: [Determining the current foreground application from a background task or service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service). Isn't it a same?