# Android notification keeps launching app

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification

I am creating a notification and when it is received the app is launched. My question is how do i stop that from happening?

```
final private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentIntent(intent)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true) 
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

The notification is called in GCMIntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String response = intent.getExtras().getString("response");

    switch(response){
        case "logout":
            String message = "You logged into another device!";
            //displayMessage(context, message);
            // notifies user
            generateNotification(context, message);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
        default:

        break;
    }



}
```

Comment: "when it is received the app is launched", you sure? not when clicked?

Comment: yes, even if i don't click on the notification the app is launched

Comment: Post where is this code called from, as I don't think problem is in here.

Comment: Do you have a service and a broadcast receiver firing over and over?  If so that's the problem

Comment: @Jasz I don't have a broadcast reciever :S

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but don't you think it is just because you start an Intent just after displaying your notification ?


`generateNotification(context, message);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);`

Your notification is displaying here right ? But you call a new Intent of your MainActivity then, which open your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do these lines which I have commented out below. That code starts an activity on the `"logout"` message received.

```
generateNotification(context, message);
//Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
//i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Excellent! That works, however now how do I run that on notification tap or if the app is open?

Comment: Have you tried tapping it? As your code seems to have that though use of `setContentIntent`

Comment: As for is app open: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not