# Check if app with [insert package name here] is currently opened?

Tags: android

I was searching android developers website but I couldn't find this option. So basically is there any possible way for my app to know if there is app with "com.android.example", opened at this moment?

Of course my app should check that through a service.

EDIT: Sorry for vague question. As opened I meant that activity (UI) is currently visible to the user.

Comment: Please provide a precise technical definition of "opened".

Comment: I have edited my question :)

Comment: Google first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not