# How to find whether app is running in background or killed android?

Tags: android, android-activity, background-foreground

I'm having requirement where i need to check whether application is running in background or killed. I'm doing like as shown below.

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

 List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : alltasks) {
                // Used to check for CALL screen
                if (aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.android.phone.InCallScreen")
                        || aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity")) {
                    // When user on call screen show a alert message
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Phone Call Screen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // Used to check for SMS screen

                if (aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList")
                        || aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity")) {
                    // When user on Send SMS screen show a alert message
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Send SMS Screen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                // Used to check for CURRENT example main screen

                String packageName = "com.sap.rex.ui";

                if (aTask.topActivity.getPackageName().equals(packageName)) {
                    isInBackground = false;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Current Example Screen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

The above code is only checking whether the top activity package name and telling whether it is in background or not.

If we open two or three application on top of it, since it only take top application package name it is saying it is not in background even though it is there.

Please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not

Comment: @Dhavalkumar Solanki I will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()) and check [importance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#importance) field against the flags defined in [RunningAppProcessInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html).  That should tell you if the app process is visible, background, or some other state.

Comment: Sure i will check and let you know