# When using Retrofit, what should I do with my calls when onPause() is called?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm new to Retrofit 2.0.  I'm making a standard call to get the data back:

```
final Call<HomeFeedContainer> call = service.getHomeFeed(token, placement);

call.enqueue(new Callback<HomeFeedContainer>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<HomeFeedContainer> call, Response<HomeFeedContainer> response) {
    //stuff
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<HomeFeedContainer> call, Throwable t) {
    //stuff
}
});
```

I noticed that the call completes successfully even if I suspend/kill the application.  I would like to use call.cancel() when this happens, but I don't have access to this local object in onPause().  If I make Call a member of my class, I can certainly cancel the call in onPause(), but I can't use the Call object to make another call.  I'll have to set this to a new Call object if I want to make the call again. This doesn't seem like the right approach.

How should I be handling my Call objects when the user suspends the app?  Thx.

Comment: `cancel()` in `onStop()` and create a new call when needed later.

Comment: Thanks azizbekian

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cancelling the ongoing api call. Use a boolean value to check whether app is in background or not.

Check if app is background or foreground : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not)

```
final Call<HomeFeedContainer> call = service.getHomeFeed(token, placement);

call.enqueue(new Callback<HomeFeedContainer>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<HomeFeedContainer> call, Response<HomeFeedContainer> response) {
    //stuff
    if(appForground){
     //do stuff related to UI and all
    }  


}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<HomeFeedContainer> call, Throwable t) {
    //stuff
}
});
```

**UPDATE** : If you want to cancel an ongoing Retrofit API call you can use call.cancel().

When  u call cancel() onFailure() method gets executed. you can use isCancelled() to check whether api call was cancelled or the device has no internet connection. for more details visit : [Link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will consider this solution.  I still think all network calls should stop if the user suspends the app.