# How do I detect when an android app is backgrounded/foregrounded, taking into account activities that focus and completely cover in-progress ones?

Tags: android

There's a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297230/1319878) of [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76002739/1319878) out there to determine if an Android app has been backgrounded/foregrounded.

But, none of them take into account launching a full screen activity, for example an in-app browser. For example, calling [launchURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent#launchUrl(android.content.Context,android.net.Uri)) will cause ON_PAUSE and ON_STOP to be called.

> If a new activity or dialog appears in the foreground, taking focus and completely covering the activity in progress, the covered activity loses focus and enters the Stopped state. The system then, in rapid succession, calls onPause() and onStop().

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes

So, how do I determine if an Android app has been backgrounded and foregrounded? By backgrounded, I mean:

- User has switched apps
- User has gone to home screen, or
- Screen has turned off

Comment: "none of them take into account launching a full screen activity, for example an in-app browser" -- that is not an in-app browser. `WebView` is an in-app browser. Custom Tabs (formerly *Chrome* Custom Tabs) start a third-party app. There is no OS-level distinction between that third-party app and any other. So, you will need to use the existing solutions (e.g., `ProcessLifecycleOwner`) augmented by your own bookkeeping for when you start a third-party app that you wish to treat as part of your app, such as Custom Tabs.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok sure, but when I open the app switcher with the web view open, it shows my app icon. It doesn't contextually switch apps for the user, so why should it for code?

On iOS, this is a *lot* easier...

Comment: "when I open the app switcher with the web view open, it shows my app icon" -- you get the same thing by default with `startActivity()` for a third-party app's activity. What you refer to as an "app switcher" is a [*task* switcher](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) and more closely resembles switching tabs in a Web browser. "It doesn't contextually switch apps for the user" -- that depends entirely on what you start and how you start it. Perhaps you would be better served using `WebView` rather than Custom Tabs.

Comment: I'm using Capacitor, so I cannot just switch.

Comment: It would appear that [Capacitor uses `WebView`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android#android-support). If you are using some plugin that steers you towards Custom Tabs, perhaps reconsider your use of that plugin.

Comment: Capacitor uses WebView for the base app, but when you launch URLs for an in-app browser experience, it uses Custom Tabs https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/main/browser/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/browser/Browser.java

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser