# How to find the screen is locked in android

Tags: android

For my application, I need to know that the screen is locked. How to check this is problematically. I used following flag:

```
if(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON != 0){
    // some code
}else if((WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)!= 0){
   // some code
}
```

But this always executing both if and else part... which flag I have to use to check the screen is locked or not?

Comment: See following links 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170563/android-detect-phone-lock-event][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317331/detecting-when-screen-is-locked][2]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170563/android-detect-phone-lock-event
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317331/detecting-when-screen-is-locked
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on

Comment: how it will execute both if and else ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968265/android-auto-logout-when-app-goes-to-background/8968763#8968763

Answer (score 23):

I'll try to answer this though the question is already old since it is unresolved and could help other googlers. ;)

First you must register a  BroadcastReceiver for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF & Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON. Note that this receiver must be registered in codes and will not work when declared in the manifest.

In your broadcast receiver, when you receive Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON, you can check if the screen is locked by using the below codes:

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean locked = km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
```

Comment: below link seems that does not need BroadcastReceiver http://stackoverflow.com/a/8668648/401403

Answer (score 3):

```
KeyguardManager myKeyManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

if( myKeyManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {

 //screen is locked

} else {

 //screen is not locked

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Register a broadcast receiver with action `android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and write your code in onReceive() method of receiver.

If you are using an activity, onPause() will be called when the screen locked and onResume() will be called when the screen unlocked.

In your code you are checking some flags, i don't know where you will do that checking ? is it continuous verification ? If you are using an activity in your app, the above procedure will happen, just check it in Android Developers website.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may have already found the answer, but if not (and for other developers), you can do it like this:

```
              PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
              boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

if (!isScreenOn) {
           //Screen is in OFF State
           //Code to power on and release lock 



                KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) this
                 .getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
               final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km
                 .newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
               kl.disableKeyguard();

               PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this
                 .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
               WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                 | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                 | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
               wakeLock.acquire();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are broadcasted intents for screen lock & unlock.

Check it like :

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){//LOGIC Here}
```

Let me know!

Comment: the above condition should be check in Braodcast receiver ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

This handles if the user has unlocked the screen, but not yet entered the home screen  or the user's screen is turned off say during a call.

```
           if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(pIntent.getAction()) ||  
                     Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(pIntent.getAction())) {
                if(mListener!=null) {
                    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                    boolean locked = km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
                    Log.v(TAG, ": Phone lock state from KEYGUARD_SERVICE: Current state:" + (locked ? "LOCKED":"UNLOCKED"));
                    mIsPhoneLocked = locked;
                }
            }
```