# Is there any way in android to check is the phone has been idle for a particular amount of time?

Tags: android

I basically want to check if the phone has been idle for a specific amount of time and if that is true then it should do some activities ... so is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Define idle? User not interacting? Phone not being moved?

Comment: idle = phone not unlocked

Answer (score 0):

Answered here:
[How to find the screen is locked in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002032/how-to-find-the-screen-is-locked-in-android)

Then you can start your timer (i.e. with a handler) and do your thing

Comment: Sorry that did not really help, do you have any link for an example of action_user_present

Comment: What shouldn't this help? As mentioned in the answer that I linked you register a BroadcastReceiver for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF & Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON

In your broadcast receiver, when you receive Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON, you can check if the screen is locked.
If it is locked you start your timer and have what you need.