# Activity starts again when lock phone screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I having the next problem. I’m developing a game. When I lock the device from the physical button and unlock it, the game starts again. The activity starts again. When I unlock it I want to continue playing from the moment I lock it.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to save the state in onPause and load it again in onResume

Comment: Yes but in my activity i have like 100 variables, there must be an easy way

Answer (score 0):

you need to [save and restore state of your activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`

[image]

[save:](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState)

> ```
> static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
> static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
> ...
>
> @Override
> public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     // Save the user's current game state
>     savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
>     savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);
>
>     // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
>     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
> }
> ```

[restore:](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState)

> ```
> public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
>     super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
>
>     // Restore state members from saved instance
>     mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
>     mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes but in my activity i have like 100 variables, there must be an easy way

Comment: you can try storing your variables to shared preferences each time they change. again even that will not be easy. I can't think of any other way as of now. instance state is the one recommended.

Comment: also, you need to carefully choose which variables to preserve, if you look carefully you may found you need not to preserve all of them

Comment: is there a way to know if the pohone was lock and unlock in the onResume method? After i unlock the cellphone i want to know ask for that, because onResume i have a method that start all again

Comment: you mean to say you are restarting everything in onResume by your code? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11623910/1529129 this might help you

Comment: Yes, thats the problem!