# How to check the phone is locked in android?

Tags: android

How to check the phone is locked or not in android?

Answer (score 0):

I attached the answer for finding the phone is locked or not,
i declared the code below,

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean locked = km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
if(locked == true){
  // do something
}else{
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Direct answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002032/how-to-find-the-screen-is-locked-in-android