# Screen Locked and Unlocked

Tags: android

I want to find out that the screen is OFF when user locked a phone in android.I used BroadCast receiver like this and registered but I am not getting the screen is off or not

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{   

    private static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF";
    BroadcastReceiver myReceiver;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
        theFilter.addAction(ACTION);

        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, theFilter);
        System.out.println("inside increate");
        myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                    System.out.println("phone locked*****");                
            }

        };   

    }}
```

How to find out this issue ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968265/android-auto-logout-when-app-goes-to-background/8968763#8968763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Delete the `private static final String ACTION` line

Step #2: Use `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` in your `addAction()` line (or, better yet, just supply it to the `IntentFilter` constructor and get rid of the `addAction()` line)

Step #3: Use `android.util.Log` instead of `System.out.println()`