# Recover static variables after app return from backgroun

Tags: android, singleton, static-variables

My app has a class that extends `Application` and another class which is an API to get data from the Internet using a singleton pattern.
When the `Application` class loads, `onCreate()` will instantiate the singleton to be used throughout the app.

At a certain point, the user my request a transportation route, which will cause Maps to load and send my app to background.
If the user return to the app soon enough (ie, the app hasn't been fully terminated yet), all the static variables from the singleton are now `null`.

What is the proper way to save those variables before going to background and retrieve them back after returning to foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Use it in `onPause` method of activity.

Comment: I know how to use them, but I need to detect when the app will go background and when it returns.

Comment: onPause -> onResume method of activity

Comment: But that will run when the Activity pauses, not the Application, right? So if I start another activity, that code is subject to be run  even though it is not needed.

Comment: Right, but there is no other callback to do it, onPause is the best and possible the only place.

Comment: I used `SharedPreferences` in combination with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6357860/1262783