# Android with Xamarin - How to run code when the user closes the App?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I found some questions/answers on how to track when the app goes to the background, like this one:
[Run code when Android app is closed/sent to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593115/run-code-when-android-app-is-closed-sent-to-background)

But I need to run the code only if the user actually closes the application.

To exemplify:

1. The user clicks on the **Overview** button;
2. The Android opens the list of thumbnail images of the recent apps;
3. The user swipe the thumbnail of my app to remove it (here is where I need to run the code).

I tried to add some code to the `OnDestroy()` method, but it don't seem to be called when I do steps above. I know the code works because I've done a test where I call the `Finish()` right at the start of my `OnCreate()`, then the `OnDestroy()` is called and so my code.

I'm using Xamarin and MvvmCross, but Java code is welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

Implement and register an instance of `Android.Content.IComponentCallbacks2` and the listen for `TrimMemory.UiHidden` events:

**LifecycleCallbacks**:

```
public class LifecycleCallbacks : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Content.IComponentCallbacks2
{
    public void OnTrimMemory(TrimMemory level)
    {
        if (level == TrimMemory.UiHidden)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Backgrounded...");
        }

    }

    public void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
    }

    public void OnLowMemory()
    {
    }
}
```

Registering an instance of `LifecycleCallbacks`:

```
[Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // ...

        Application.RegisterComponentCallbacks(new LifecycleCallbacks());

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Native android developer here, I'm not sure if Xamarin extends the native framework somehow making this possible, but natively it's currently not supported.

The OS does not necessarily call activities' `onDestroy` method when the app is killed, but when the Activity is killed. It's really different because the App can be killed without calling activities' `onDestroy` and the `onDestroy` can be called without the Application being killed.

I recommend looking up to Services and the Alarm Manager to actually track when this occurs, allied to the `onDestroy` and `onPause` methods. The precision in that case will be as good as you want. You can call an alarm every minute to check it for example, or run a background service in its own process that will remain active after the application is killed.

There's a [comprehensive discussion about this in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593115/run-code-when-android-app-is-closed-sent-to-background). It's about native code, but the explanation of the problem is very useful for you to understand the limits of the framework.