# Android : Check if app is closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an alarm broadcast receiver where I want to check if my app is completely closed, which means app is neither running in foreground nor background.

Can anyone tells me how can I check this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593115/run-code-when-android-app-is-closed-sent-to-background This should hold all answers you need

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `service` and   overwrite the `onTaskRemoved()` method

From the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent))

> the user has removed a task means swiping the app out from the task
>   list. Stopping the Service from the phone's settings does not trigger
>   Service.onTaskRemoved().

Code:

```
 public class AppStopped extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Service", "Service Started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("Service", "Service Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("Service", "END");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Code here
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

In Manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.example.AppStopped" 
     android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Start the service in your activity like:

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AppStopped.class));
```

Comment: I have tried this, but onTaskRemoved is not called when app is killed by OS.\

Answer (score -1):

In your Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {    
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        // your app is closed
    }
}
```